Automatic redirect from http:// to https:// for all chromium browsers
I am not able to turn off automatic redirect from http://site.xyz to https://site.xyz.
When i use any chromium browser I got redirect from http://site.xyz to https://site.xyz
When i use iphone browser there is not redirect.
I use cloudflare for dns and https. Automatic http -> https redirects turned off. Development mode is turned on to turn off the cache
I suppose chromium prowsers prefer to use https version insted of http and make automatic redirect.
But i don't know how to fix this. I do not need this automatic redirect
There is no redirect in html code or in nginx configuration.
Here are redirect headers in chrome
HTTP/1.1 307 Internal Redirect
Location: https://site.xyz/
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: Cross-Origin
Non-Authoritative-Reason: DNS
So i need to understand why chromium browsers make this redirect for my domain.
Thanks in advance
I tried to turn off cache on cloudflare and turned off autmatic http to https redirects.
I expect to turn off automatic redirect from http -> https.
